# Assign a value (got from an xml file) to an attribute of Woocommerce products

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Good morning,
I should need to assign a value (value) from an xml file (that I export from my Warehouse Management System to My wordpress site) to an attribute I have already created 'unita'.
And each time i update that file, it would update the attribute value.

Alternatively, it would be fine creating a new attribute from that xml value.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: How are you importing this? What's the XML structure look like?

Comment: The structure is like this [Danea](https://www.danea.it/software/easyfatt/ecommerce/integrazione/invio-prodotti/), where you read ESEMPIO.
I import it through a plugin created for my Warehouse Management System [Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-importer-for-danea/).

Comment: So then the WC Importer authors would probably be the best people to ask about adding custom data.. though can see they aren't great at answering forum posts.

Comment: Though looking at the source of the free version I don't see any obvious points of extension. Maybe the premium version has more options.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The data is already in each product and in the xml inside the plugin folder. I "just" would need of the code to take this data an make an attribute with it.